# Safari does not trigger form Submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, safari

For a project I got two select-formfields that get sent via jquery trigger("submit");
This works well in Firefox und Chrome, but in Safari nothing happens.

This is the HTML-Code:

```
<body>
    <form action="http://google.de" target="_blank" style="display: inline;" method="get">
    <select class="bstarch2" data-role="none" name="q">
        <option value="none">Please choose</option>
        <option value="a: worked">A</option>
        <option value="b: worked">B</option>
    </select>
</form>
<select class="bstarch" data-role="none">
    <option value="none">Please choose</option>
    <option value="http://google.de">Google</option>
    <option value="http://en.wikipedia.org">Wikipedia</option>
</select>
<form action="" method="get" target="_blank" id="mmform"></form>
</body>
```

And this the Javascript code:

```
$("body").on("change", ".bstarch", function () {
    if ($(this).val() != "none") {
        $("#mmform").attr("action", $(this).val());
        $("#mmform").trigger("submit");
        $(this).val("none");
    }
});

$("body").on("change", ".bstarch2", function () {
    if ($(this).val() != "none") {
        $(this).parent().trigger("submit");
        $(this).val("none");
    }
});
```

I got a jsfiddle here, and as well it does not work with Safari:
http://jsfiddle.net/P7vNX/

Thanks for any help.

**EDIT:
Got it:
It seems that safari blocks the form submit as a popup.
The code is correct, but it gets blocked by Safari...**
*Can't answer my question because my reputation is to small.*

Answer (score 3):

Using Safari version 11.1.2 (13605.3.8) on a desktop Mac: if target="_blank" is specified within a *form* tag, submitting the form fails. That same form works as expected on other browsers. Remove the target="_blank" specification and the form works properly. The same form with target="_blank" does work as expected on other browsers including Chrome, Firefox and IE.

I can only assume this failure to support the "target" attribute is a Safari defect. A possible work-around would be to use "javascript:window.open()" instead of the URL as the action.

Comment: Thanks! You saved me from hours of head-scratching!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use jQuery in place of $ ,

```
     jQuery("body").on("change", ".bstarch", function () {
      if (jQuery(this).val() != "none") {
       jQuery("#mmform").attr("action", $(this).val());
       jQuery("#mmform").trigger("submit");
       jQuery(this).val("none");
      }
    });
```

Comment: Sadly this does not solve the problem, it still does not work in safari.